# Using racadm in posh-ssh and powershell

Tags: powershell, posh-ssh

I'm running a racadm command to find the number of Core count on the Posh-Ssh module, would anyone know how to count the total amount?

```
$get_CoreInfo = Invoke-SSHCommand -Index 0 -command "racadm get BIOS.ProcSettings" 
Core_Number = ($get_CoreInfo.Output -match '(.*)NumCores=' -replace '(.*)NumCores=' )
```

gives you this output: `8 8` but I would like the complete amount.

Also any idea how to get the CPU Count? Can't seem to see anything in the documentation.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the numbers in your final output are split by a white space, then try this:

```
$get_CoreInfo = Invoke-SSHCommand -Index 0 -command "racadm get BIOS.ProcSettings" 
$core_number_string = ($get_CoreInfo.Output -match '(.*)NumCores=' -replace '(.*)NumCores=')
$core_number = 0
foreach($cpu in ($core_number_string -split " ")){[int]$core_number += [int]$cpu}
```